# Restore form values when returning to page in iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ios, forms, google-chrome

Here's how it works in Safari on iOS (and this is the behaviour I want):

If I enter some text into a text field on a page, click a link on the page which loads another page and then returns to the previous page using the back button, the text I entered into the text field is still there.

Using Chrome on iOS, this does not work, however. The textfield is empty when returning to the page.

Is there an explanation for this and is there a solution? Using localeStorage and a cookie to cache the form data doesn't feel like a good solution, as I have to keep track of when that data should be removed from the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. After much researching and testing, I concluded that it's a bug for Chrome. I hope Google will fix it soon. Here's the bug report I logged:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470398